# Trying to trigger azure pipeline from another pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have two pipelines Pipeline A and Pipeline B. I want to trigger pipeline A after a particular stage in pipeline B is successful. I have below logic in pipeline A:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: Triggering pipeline
      source: B     
      trigger:  
        branches:
          include:
          - master*
          - main*
        stages: 1
```

Pipeline B has two stages 1&2 and stage 2 depends on stage1. When I run above logic, after stage1 is successful it triggers pipeline A and also after stage 2 ran it is triggering pipeline A.
Is it possible to just trigger the pipeline after stage 1?